# Cannot convert value of type 'Published<[StepsEntity]>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, combine

**StepsEntity is a core data entity**

Receiving the following error when attempting to display a string value in a TextField: "Cannot convert value of type 'Published<[StepsEntity]>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding'"

I know this is because StepsEntity in my core data model is @Published. @Published works great here as it allows all the data to be updated neatly. How can I display an @Published in a TextField?

Below is the piece where I am receiving the error:

```
List {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                if let recipeSteps = (vm.recipes[vm.getRecordsCount() - 1].steps?.allObjects as? [StepsEntity])?.sorted { $0.stepNumber < $1.stepNumber } {
                    
                    if (textFieldCount == 1) {
                        //do nothing
                    } else if (textFieldCount > 1) {
                        ForEach(recipeSteps, id: \.stepNumber) { index in
                            HStack {
                               
                                Text(String(index.stepNumber) + ".").bold()
                                TextField("", text: vm.$recipeSteps) //This is where the error is seen
                                
                            }
                        }.onDelete(perform: { index in
                            self.vm.deleteRecipeSteps(at: index, from: vm.recipes[vm.getRecordsCount() - 1])
                            })
                    }
                
                }
            }
```

vm.recipeSteps refers to my CoreDataRelationshipViewModel, which is where all core data functions are handled. this is declared in the view struct as:

```
@StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()
```

Here is a snippet from the CoreDataRelationshipViewModel class:

```
class CoreDataRelationshipViewModel: ObservableObject {

let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
@Published var recipes: [RecipeEntity] = []
@Published var recipeSteps: [StepsEntity] = []

init() {
    getRecipes()
}

func getRecipes() { ////more functions for retrieving, deleting, etc. in this section
```

I have tried converting the Published var to a binding but no luck:

```
TextField("", text: Binding(vm.$recipeSteps)!)
```

I have also tried referencing the recipeSteps declared in the if let statement within the list, but that does not work either.

I have been at it for a few days, and I think I have exhausted all options. Open to all ideas here. Maybe I need to rebuild my model?

Thoughts?

--Edits--

Upper portion of struct, where variables are created:

```
struct AddItemView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
@State var frameDimensions: CGFloat = 0
@State var imageButtonText: String = "Click To Add Image"
@State var imageToUpload: Data

@StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State var stepInfo: String = ""
@State var textFieldCount: Int = 1
@State var stepNumber: [Int]
@State var recordsCount = 1
@State var errorText = ""
@State var stepErrorColor = Color.white.opacity(0)
@State var nameErrorColor = Color.white.opacity(0)

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
```

Comment: `TextField` expects a binding to a `String`, because it updates the property through that binding based on the string that it contains. What are you trying to accomplish  when you attempt to update `recepeSteps`, which is an array of some objects

Comment: The end goal is if a user updates an item in the list of textfields, the updated value will replace the original value in CoreData. Think of a to do list, you create the to do list and then you realize you made a typo. As a user, I would go back and edit the misspelling. The update should then save to core data. Currently focused on returning the value in a textfield first, then will deal with the saving the update to core data later.

Comment: Sure, but you're trying to create a binding to the array - not to the string property. TextField can only update a string property. Maybe you want to update the individual item. Then you'd need something like this: `TextField("", text: $vm.recepeSteps[index].someStringProp)` where `someStringProp` is a property you are updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restructuring the way my core data save works. Instead of saving item by item, I am now looping through a for in loop to save data all at the end. This allows me to display the data locally via some state variables, but then save the full array to my core data entity.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that

```swift
TextField("", text: vm.$recipeSteps)
```

should actually be

```swift
TextField("", text: $vm.recipeSteps)
```

as you need to pass the view model with Binding rather than `recipeSteps` (which, when using `$` to pass it beyond `vm`'s dot accessor, passes a generic `Publisher`).

Also, this would only work if the `@Published` property in your view model conforms to `StringProtocol` (is a string). Are you sure `recipeSteps` is a string that can be edited via `TextField`?

Comment: I am seeing an issue where it cannot find "$vm" in scope. Is there something additional that needs to be done to get this to work? Additionally, recipesteps may be an NSSet that contains string values. Does this change the approach? --Edit, it is "public class StepsEntity : NSManagedObject" - looks like it is an NSManagedObject

Comment: If `@StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()` is called within your View with the List, then `vm` should show up in scope. Honestly, I'm not sure if `TextField`s work with an `NSSet` of strings, but if it doesn't throw an error after sorting out your `vm`, then I'd imagine it would be fine. Perhaps elements in that array are separated by newlines in the `TextField`.

Comment: Currently there are no new lines separating the data. "vm" does show up in scope, but "$vm" does not. Could it be because a textfield expects string binding, but I am passing it an nsmanagedobject?

Comment: I find it odd that `$vm` doesn't appear in scope. Could you edit your post to include the declaration of `vm` within your View struct? Maybe we can get a fuller picture that way. [Edit: Thank you!]

Comment: Added the top portion of the struct. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Looks like it is instantiated in the correct location. The only thing that I can imagine would cause it to not appear in scope is, as you said, the fact that you're passing an `NSManagedObject`. Try using just a normal `String` via a new `@Published` property, then work from there.

Comment: Looks like it could have been an issue with Xcode. Restarted it. Error now reads "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[StepsEntity]>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'". It can now find it in scope, but needs to be of type string. Getting closer! Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234235/discussion-between-ben-myers-and-nickreps).